# MySQL Full text search AND operator

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb

Is it possible to use full test search in InnoDB engine with AND operator for natural language mode? I mean query like below but with all words as required:

```
SELECT *, MATCH (body)  AGAINST ('mysql database') AS score FROM post ORDER BY score DESC;
```

For this query i want return all records which match both words:'mysql' AND 'database'. I know i can use + and BOOLEAN mode, but it causes another problems like other operators which i want to ignore (*,-,"'..)

Comment: The score should be higher if both words are matched, isn't it?

Comment: @Barmar I want return only records where ALL words matched - and score should be computed only for those records for better performance.

Comment: Then you need `+` and `IN BOOLEAN MODE`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `WHERE` clause that tests for each word separately:

```
SELECT *, MATCH (body)  AGAINST ('mysql database') AS score 
FROM post 
WHERE MATCH(body) AGAINST ('mysql') AND MATCH(body) AGAINST('database')  
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Comment: I thought about this, but what about performance? I have queries consists of 3 to 10 words, will performance be better in BOOLEAN mode with '+' as prefix assuming i want score computing? Also it would be nice to prepare that syntax dynamically based on just query phrase. For example i have query 'How to parse json to object in java' which i pass to JMeter which should query mysql..

Comment: Boolean search would almost certainly be better, but you said you couldn't use that.

Comment: I dont have any restrictions to use boolean, i just thought it would be better to do it in some way with natural mode because i have queries which contains some strange characters like *,- etc which i want treat as simple strings - can i easily ignore them in boolean mode? Just need to prepare queries with AND operator and for phrase taken direcly from user where any special characters are ignored and do it with best performance (because i make performance testing) .